# Почему Android Studio не распознает Meizu M5?

Tags: android, android-studio, отладка, usb

В настройках Meizu включил пункт "USB-отладка", пробовал скачивать драйвера, предназначенные, судя по описанию, для Meizu M5, после установки драйверов устройство не распознается... При этом отладка со старенького Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini работает исправно.
Может быть, у кого-то была похожая проблема, либо кто-то просто знает или догадывается, как решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @PASHAKRIZSKY, вы пробовали в статус баре менять варианты подключения устройства? "зарядка через USB/mtp/ptp" попробуйте менять и через секунд 10-15 проверять, увидит ли студия его

Comment: @zayn1991 в статус баре? А где это?)

Comment: при подключении бывает же уведомление о подключении

Comment: @PASHAKRIZSKY посмотрите вот по этой ссылке, я ответил на похожий вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646637/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-xiaomi-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%ba/646685#646685

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях я применяю [Wifi ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb). Единственный минус, утилита требует рута.

А в остальном отличная альтернатива USB шнуру.

Comment: Точно помню, что пользовался [ADB Wireless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=za.co.henry.hsu.adbwirelessbyhenry) без рута во времена актуальности Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0). Так что не факт, что рут это требование.

Comment: сейчас точно требуется рут: **This app works on ROOTED devices only**

Comment: По моей ссылке другое приложение. Там всё ещё `*** NO ROOT REQUIRED ***` в описании.

Comment: Ну видимо зависит от API level

Answer (score 1):

Мне, в этой ситуации, помогли драйвера установленные на самом телефоне.
Порядок действий:

1) В зоне уведомлений на телефоне меняем тип подключения на "Встроенный CD-ROM". После этого в системе (на компьютере) появится ещё один CD-ROM с именем IAmCdRom.

2) Копируете с этого CD-ROMа папку USB drivers себе на компьютер.

3) Меняете тип подключения на Медиа-устройство (MTP). В менеджере устройств компьютера появляется MTP устройство с неустановленными драйверами. Обновляете драйвера указав их расположение.

4) На телефоне появится всплывающее сообщение "Разрешить USB отладку с данного компьютера" и чекбокс "разрешать всегда". Соглашаетесь.

5) Вуаля! Андроид-Студия видит ваш Meizu M5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема с Xiaomi, помогла замена шнура USB :)

Comment: Пробовал два кабеля - не помогло)

Comment: Google usb тоже скачивал в sdk settings?